# Slots are missing in custom defineCustomElement implementation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, vite, custom-element

We are working in a web component library using Vue 3, TS and Tailwind. We are using a custom implementation for defineCustomElement macro, [where @tony19 was able to give plugins support like vue-router and pinia](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-nested-custom-elements-lose-styles?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue). Every single feature works flawless, except slots.

Here a link with a @tony19 example fork using this custom macro and repro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-nested-custom-elements-lose-styles-gtj3fy?file=src/App.vue

How could I fix this issue?

I was trying to pass slots via setup function, then return a h function with {...slots } but without success. Until there, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hey Cesar! Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue with slots not working correctly when doing a custom implementation for defineCustomElement :(

Comment: @jsweet59 I'm using https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-vue-ce.

Comment: @jsweet59 please check my answer might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, but based on [yyx990803](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/6142#issuecomment-1311364361) comment is not possible

My work around:

// MyCustomElement.ce.vue

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="header">
            <slot name="header">Default Header</slot>
        </div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
    //Code
</script>
```

// The function do define custom element with shared data

```js
function createElementInstance({ component, app, renderOptions = {} } = {}){

    return defineCustomElement({
        setup() {
            const inst = getCurrentInstance()

            Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context)
            Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides)
        },
        render: () => h(component, null, renderOptions)
    })
}
```

```js
import MyCustomElementfrom './MyCustomElement.ce.vue'
const app = createApp()
customElements.define('my-custom-element', createElementInstance({
   app,
   component: MyCustomElement,
   // Create WebComponents Slots and pass them to Our Component.
   {
      default: () => h('slot'),
      header: () => h('slot', { name: 'header' }),

   }
}))
```

The above way is not ideal as we have to define the slots multiple times, but it works in case you need to share same `app` instance between custom elements.

More advanced usage with DynamicImport and Styles [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Froxz/pen/OJdqJyM?editors=0010)

Comment: Ok, now, the issue here is how to pass dynamic slots to renderOptions with eases. I think I have a rough idea.

Comment: @CesarGomez Updated my answer: added CodePen with `DynamicImports`, `Styles`

https://codepen.io/Froxz/pen/OJdqJyM?editors=0010

Answer (score -1):

So you have something like this in your main.ts file

```
defineCustomElement({
    styles: component.styles,
    props: component.props,
    setup(props, { slots }) {
        const app = createApp();
        plugins.forEach(plugin => {
            app.use(plugin);
        });
        const inst = getCurrentInstance();
        Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context);
        Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides);
        return () =>
            h(component, {
                ...props,
                ...slots
            });
    }
});
```

And if you inspect that slots variable it's always empty, even when the custom element has something like

```
<my-component><div>hmmm...</div></my-component>
```

It appears to be a bug, an alternative way to making this work is to move the setup code in main.ts into your main App.vue setup and using that for your custom element. So App.vue setup would have something like:

```
// Plugin initialization and the list can probably be exported from main.ts, putting this here for simplicity
import router from './router';
const plugins = [plugins];

const app = createApp();
plugins.forEach(plugin => {
    app.use(plugin);
});
const inst = getCurrentInstance();
Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context);
Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides);
```

Then main.ts would be reduced to

```
const styles: string[] = [];
const modules = import.meta.glob('./**/*.vue');

for (const path in modules) {
    const mod = await modules[path]();
    styles.push(mod.default.styles);
}

App.styles = [styles.flat().join('')];

customElements.define('swim-app', defineCustomElement(App));
```

Any slots defined in the App component should now work. You can ignore the styles stuff above, that just fixes another bug where child styles aren't included in the shadow dom styles tag.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, but I'm not using App.vue and I don't see how moving code from main.ts to App.vue will solve the issue. In fact, the code you describe I have placed as an utility (not a composable).